# How to create huge random document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, random, database

I am newbie with MongoDB. I'm trying to create a database which will be included 10,000 data. The data will contain "username" and "Birthday".

I want to create 10,000 data with random username and birthday. Do we have a fastest way to create this kind of database?.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Make a program that does it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some functions that will help you to create a random string(name) and random date since 1950 untill 2000 and insert it into mongodb.

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function getRandomDate() {
    // aprox nr of days since 1970 untill 2000: 30years * 365 days
    var nr_days1 = 30*365;
    // aprox nr of days since 1950 untill 1970: 20years * 365 days
    var nr_days2 = -20*365;

    // milliseconds in one day
    var one_day=1000*60*60*24

    // get a random number of days passed between 1950 and 2000
    var days = getRandomInt(nr_days2, nr_days1);

    return new Date(days*one_day)
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {    
  db.test.insert( 
    { 
      name : "name"+i, 
      birthday: getRandomDate() 
    } 
  ) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Seem this is decent function to work on with.  But, I'm still confused in the "name" part. If I want to create a list of string and the its name gonna be generated by those string, it could be pleasant more than the "name1, name2, name3...."? @Sergiu Zaharie

Comment: You can generate ransom strings, take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

Best way will be read off docs about random generate in mongodb.
https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/tutorial/generate-test-data/
Also you could use special service for generate random data.
For example:
https://www.mockaroo.com/

Comment: Thank you so much. It's kindda useful to me. :)  @Rider_BY. Do we have able to create a function to do this stuff?. If we could do it, do we still have to insert one by one for its name and birthday?

Answer (score 3):

I have try `mgeneratejs`, very easy to use, [mgeneratejs](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mgeneratejs)

here is sample command, `mgeneratejs` print data to `stdout`, then use `mongoimport` import these data into `mongod`:

```
mongodb-osx-x86_64-4.0.1 $ mgeneratejs '{"name": "$name", "age": "$age", "emails": {"$array": {"of": "$email", "number": 3}}}' -n 5 | mongoimport --uri mongodb://localhost:27017/test --collection user --mode insert
2018-08-09T16:19:13.295+0800    connected to: localhost
2018-08-09T16:19:14.544+0800    imported 5 documents
```

Comment: Life saver mate!